# Multiple axis breaks

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to create a plot on Matlab with multiple axis breaks (so something like the following):

[image]

I've tried using things like `breakyaxis` and `breakaxis` from the Matlab File Exchange, but those only allow for one break, not multiple.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Off the top of my head... use NaN in your data set to represent a break, and use custom tick labels to label around the breaks.

Comment: siliconwafer -- I have three datasets and want to break between each one. Is there anyway to do that? Sorry if I'm being dumb...

Comment: concatenate them and insert a `NaN` between each dataset. Create an cell array of the `X` labels (not forgetting an empty string for the `NaN` values) and set that as `xticklabel`

Answer (score 4):

The `NaN` (***N**ot **a N**umber*) values can be an annoying thing but also a convenient one in some case.

When you plot data, Matlab will leave a blank in place of every data point which has no value (the `NaN`). So the principle is to insert these `NaN` between your datasets and tell Matlab to plot the whole lot. Matlab will leave a blank automatically everywhere there is a `NaN`.

Here is an example, since you didn't supply sample data I first have to define 3 short data sets resembling the ones you have in your figure:

```
%% // sample data sets
yf = @(x) 2*x+40+randi(7,size(x)) ;
x1 = 57:61 ; y1 = yf(x1) ;
x2 = 72:76 ; y2 = yf(x2) ;
x3 = 80:83 ; y3 = yf(x3) ;
```

This is an edited answer to take into account the breaks in the Y axis. To be able to call global operations on the datasets I have to regroup them into a cell array or a structure. The struture approach would use loops on the different data sets, while the cell array allow the use of `cellfun` to compact the code. I chose this approach and use `cellfun` extensively.

So first step is put all your data sets in a cell array

```
%% // have to group the data sets in a cell array or structure to implement global operations
xc = { x1 ; x2 ; x3 } ;
yc = { y1 ; y2 ; y3 } ;
```

Now the heavy part:

```
%// find the maximum vertical span of the datasets and the total span
maxVal = cellfun(@max,yc) ;
minVal = cellfun(@min,yc) ;
maxYspan  = max( maxVal-minVal ) ;
totalSpan = max(maxVal)-min(minVal) ;

%// find a sensible Y value to add between the datasets, not too wide but
%// enough to see a break`
yBreakIncrement = round( totalSpan / 10 ) ; %// adjust that if necessary
yTickIncrement = round( maxYspan /5 ) ;     %// adjust that if necessary

%% // rebuild the Y datasets 
%// value to substract to each data set to bring them together (including the break space)
setSubstract = [0 ; cumsum( (minVal(2:end)-maxVal(1:end-1))- yBreakIncrement )  ] ;
%// get 3 new data sets brought together
Yall = cellfun(@minus , yc , num2cell(setSubstract) , 'uni',0) ;
%// concatenate the data sets, inserting NaN in the middle
Yall = cellfun( @(a,b) cat(2,a,b) , Yall , repmat({NaN},length(yc),1) , 'uni',0) ;
Yall = cat( 2, Yall{:} ) ;
%// remove the last trailing NaN
Yall(end) = [] ;

%% // Build the Y labels
%// generate ticks that covers each interval
Y_tickpos = cellfun(@colon, num2cell(minVal), repmat({yTickIncrement},length(yc),1) , num2cell(maxVal) , 'uni',0) ;
%// generate the Y labels based the real Y values
Y_labels  = cellstr( num2str( cat(2, Y_tickpos{:} ).') ) ;   %'// ignore this comment
%// now adjust the actual position
Y_tickpos = cellfun(@minus , Y_tickpos , num2cell(setSubstract) , 'uni',0) ;
Y_tickpos = cat( 2, Y_tickpos{:} ) ;

%% // Build the X labels (and axis)
%// create a continuous index for the X axis
X = 1:length(Yall) ; 
X_labels = cellstr( num2str( cat(2, xc{:} ).') ) ;  %'// generate the X labels based the X values
X_tickpos = X(~isnan(Yall)) ;                       %// prepare a vector for the label positions

%% // Display
plot(X,Yall) %// plot as usual 

%// Set the labels at the chosen positions
set(gca, 'XTick' , X_tickpos , 'XTickLabel' , X_labels )
set(gca, 'YTick' , Y_tickpos , 'YTickLabel' , Y_labels )
```

That should give you something like:
[image: axis break]

Hopefully enough to get you started. Try to adapt the principle to your data.